# VMWare Fusion 6 Nat translation issue

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, nat, vmware-fusion

I have the following network diagram, using VMWare Fusion 6
[image: Network Diagram]

I am able to ping from the en0 interface on my mac to all of the 172.16 network, and on the custom linux kernel (2.6.x) base I can ping the NAT server and the host side nic but I can't ping the 192 network.  The Nat isn't translating to the 192 network.  I thought maybe since 192 is a private network that it won't translate but it doesn't work with any network on the other side.

I also tried to put the VM on a host only network and add a route to the 192 network manually, and it still failed to work (VM to host).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using two different subnets?  If you bridge your NIC, the guest would be on the same network as the Mac and you'd be able to communicate fluidly.

Comment: I can't use the bridge network, I need to have the vm a statically assigned ip address, and I can't statically assign it on the 192 network not an admin.

Comment: Are you trying to NAT a service? Or trying to allow a route from `172.16.0.0/16` to `192.168.1.0/24`?

Comment: I want to route from the 172 net to the 192 net, I can't bridge the vm to be on the 192 net.  Is there a work around where I can put it as a host only vmnetwork and still connect to the external net, without using NAT.  NAT is what is failing right now.

Comment: If you don't need NAT, then the solution is simple; build a route.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Verify a route exists on your linux box for 192.168.1.0/24:

```
netstat -rn
```

You'd be looking for something like:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     172.16.225.1    255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         172.16.225.4     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

If you don't have a route for `192.168.1.0/24` you can add it manually.

Example:

```
route add 192.168.1.0 subnet 255.255.255.0 gateway 172.16.225.1
```

This means any traffic headed for `192.168.1.0/24` from your linux box, would route to 172.16.225.1, and from there, 172.16.225.1 should route it the final destination

If you already have a route built for `192.168.1.0/24` then you need to check your firewall settings

Comment: I have tried this, sorry I will edit my question to include this fact.  It still didn't work.

Comment: show me your routing table and a traceroute